# Can jquery add closing element tags (markup) only?

Tags: jquery, html, append

Given this nth row in a table, can jquery add only the markup to close the table

```
        <tr class="eop">
            <td> 8/31 </td>
            <td> XYZ </td>
            <td> 2 </td>
            <td> 92.00 </td>
        </tr>

   </tbody>            --
</table>                 |
<table>                  --     //  inserted markup
   head jquery var       |
   <tbody>             --
```

What I'm trying is to use:

```
$('tr.eop').append("</tbody></table><table>+head+<tbody>");   // head = table header
```

Comment: Nope, not really! Valid markup with entire DOM elements only, if you're using DOM insertion methods etc.

Comment: Since jQuery manipulates the DOM and the DOM consists of objects it is not possible to insert html fragments with Javascript / jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOM consists of element nodes, the opening and closing tags mean nothing once an element is part of the DOM or a DOM Fragment.

You cannot attach elements to the page that do not have a closing tag. If the closing tag is omitted, one will be created for you. You also cannot close a parent element by appending a closing tag as a child, it will instead simply create a new complete element inside the parent element.

If you want to create a new table, create a new table.

```
var newTable = $("<table><thead>"+head+"</thead><tbody></tbody></table>");
$('tr.eop').closest("table").after(newTable)
$('tr.eop').nextAll().appendTo(newTable.find("tbody"));
```

Comment: Sounds like a great explanation. I need a few to process this. Thanks.

Comment: That works great. May I edit to insert `<thead>"+head+"</thead>` into the 1st line?

Comment: Interestingly, your edit to combine 2nd & 3rd rows of code causes `Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3`. I have to leave it as you originally wrote for it to work.

Comment: very odd indeed.  i'll go back to original then.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. See if it works.

```
var tt = $('tr.eop');
tt.innerHTML = tt.innerHTML + '</tbody></table><table>'+head+'<tbody>';
```

Comment: No it doesn't work, because the second `innerHTML` results in `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If not a good practice, however it works **(I'm not sure if it can fail at some point)**, take a look to this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/MKSqy/

However I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, you can easily do something similar by manipulating the DOM tree. Or changing the way you are building the app, instead of using tables use divs and create a hidden  or  that is shown when you want.

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div>8/31</div>
        <div> XYZ </div>
        <div> 2 </div>
        <div> 92.00 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="head" style="visible:none;"></div>
</div>
```

and manipulate the css to create a table style. I recommend this just for just case, however **table** tag exist for a reason and you shouldnt abuse of **divs**.

**EDIT: I didnt understand very well so this is what you need**

http://jsfiddle.net/MKSqy/1/

What this does is basically select the next elements after the nth element and create a table and append it right next to the preovious table. So you dont have to handle the close tags.

Comment: That jsfiddle example is interesting. I can't see how it is working... The goal of the question is to split a long table that might take 2 print pages.

Comment: If you inspect element, you will see that what it is really doing is inserting a new table inside of the td, not creating a new table.

Comment: Yeah my bad I didn't understand very well, and the code wasn't working as expected (comboooo-breaker) Check this another solution that might help:

http://jsfiddle.net/MKSqy/1/