# jQuery create element by template <element />

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I can easily create new element with jQuery:

```
var $e = $("<element>");
```

The result after appending will be:

```
<element></element>
```

But I really need:

```
<element/>
```

How to reach the desirable result?
For example, how to create:

```
<path id="p2" d="M0,0"/>
```

I tried `$("<path/>")`, `$("<path />")`, but it not works. I believe, that:

```
$("#parent").html("<path id='p2'/>");
var $p = $("#p2");
$p.attr({'d': "M0,0"});
...
```

will work, but this is the **nightmare** for me

---

**UPDATE 1**:

Even `$("#parent").html("<group><path id='p2'/></group>");` is not working! It produces:

```
<... id="parent"><group><path id='p2'></path></group></...>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**:

Even `$parent[0].innerHTML = '<group><path id="p1"/></groups>';` produces:

```
<... id="parent"><group><path id='p2'></path></group></...>
```

Comment: Why does it matter if the tag self closes or not?  In fact, self closing tags don't even exist in HTML5

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do and why it matters if it is self-closing? And perhaps provide a reproducible case for people to look at.

Comment: @ExplosionPills He __did__ specify `xhtml` as a tag, but I get your point.

Comment: jQuery makes an internal call to `document.createElement`, so I would think it would generate the correct markup depending on the specific tag, wouldn't it? Just a thought. Have you tried with different elements (<input> vs. <div>) and noticed a difference?

Comment: [Can jquery add closing element tags (markup) only?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736398/can-jquery-add-closing-element-tags-markup-only

Comment: It is necessary to produce and reach SVG elements inside HTML. SVG have `<element/>` notation in graphic primitives.

Comment: Thank for everyone. Guys, you all very kind!

Comment: @user1543083 - You are asking the wrong question. I think you should be asking "How can I use jquery to successfully insert SVG elements into the DOM?"

Comment: Yes, I did. But SVG tags the same tags as regular html tags. Even `<path .../>` tag. For example, with the animation it is looks like `<path ...><animation ... /></path>`. But the question is wider than the svg portion in html. It is about xml `<tag/>` notation. And the right answer is "there is no chance to do it". It is no problem, because `<path ...></path>` works as well, and I have to just avoid `<hr/>` and `<br/>` in html.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#parent").html("<path id='p2'/>");`

If in the above statement you want the value to display of ` in a tag or attribute with id='parent', it has to be as the following:

`$("#parent").html(document.getElementById('p2'));`

Comment: Sorry, but `$("#p2")` will produce only `<div></div>` pair.

Comment: it is a part of the SVG element on a page