# Jquery .insertBefore ignores closing tag and auto closes missing tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to split a div called "foo" into two div's by closing the first and then opening a new one with the same class, using .insertBefore. But jquery will ignore the div closing tag and auto complete the div with the missing closing tag.

```
$( '</div><div class="foo">' ).insertBefore( 'h2:first' );
```

I get this:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<h2>Title</h2>
```

But want to accomplish this:

```
</div><div class="foo">
<h2>Title</h2>
```

I am trying to split one div called "foo" into two div's, by closing the existing one, and then adding a new opening tag it will result in two div's "foo".

Any solutions to this?

Full html structure: ( i want to split this a couple of times in smaller blocks of "foo". All contents from "foo" come from the database and I cannot manipulate it otherwise than using jquery/js.

```
<div class="foo">
    <span>Text here</span>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h3>Another title</h3>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h3>Another title</h3>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML you're trying to change from?

Comment: Your HTML is normalized when it is parsed. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make sense. Please expand on html structure and why you are trying to do this

Comment: @charlietfl I believe it does make sense. Maybe OP is just trying to end one div and add another...

Comment: Remember that jQuery is working with a document, not a string of HTML - wanted to add closing tags is a sign that you're mistaken about what's already *in* the DOM (hint: it won't be an open tag needing closure).

Comment: @Jonathan Understandable desire, not at all how jQuery and the DOM actually work. There's a misunderstanding behind the question.

Comment: What is the misunderstanding? I try to split one div called "foo" into two div's, by closing the existing one, and then adding a new opening tag it will result in two div's "foo".

Comment: @coder the dom only contains complete elements...it's not a text editor. You need to show the html structure you are trying to modify and show expected results

Comment: I have added the dom structure, trying to split it into multiple blocks of "foo"

Answer (score 1):

This will move everything beginning with the first `h2` into a new `div`, placed immediately after the `h2`'s parent.  It uses the `contents()` method to include text nodes:

```js
var h2 = $('h2:first'),
    hp = h2.parent(),
    move;

$('<div class="foo"/>')
  .insertAfter(hp)
  .append(hp.contents().filter(function() { //use contents() to include text nodes
    move = move || $(this).is(h2);          //move everything beginning with the first h2
    return move;
  }));
```

```css
.foo {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <span>Text here</span>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Text</p>
  Text node here.
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Text</p>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Text</p>
  <h3>Another title</h3>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Text</p>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Text</p>
  <h3>Another title</h3>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to parse it all as a string, you could simply insert a new div after the one you want to split, and move some of the content into it.

```js
jQuery(function() {
    var $moving = $('h2:first, h2:first ~ *');
    $('<div class="foo"></div>')
        .insertAfter($moving.parent())
        .append($moving);
});
```

```css
.foo {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>dummy paragraph</p>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>dummy paragraph</p>
    <p>dummy paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Note: If you have text nodes as direct children of foo, they will not be moved. For your example HTML, this is a non-issue.

If you ***really*** want to do this on an HTML string level, I suppose you could convert the outer DOM element to an HTML string, and do a string place before resetting the HTML.

But be warned, this recreates the entire content for this element and it's siblings, and any element references and event listeners will be orphaned.

```js
jQuery(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('h2:first').parent().parent();
    $wrapper.html($wrapper.html().replace('<h2', '</div><div class="foo"><h2'))
});
```

```css
.foo {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>dummy paragraph</p>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>dummy paragraph</p>
    <p>dummy paragraph</p>
</div>
```

You can limit this effect to just the DIV you are targeting using the native `outerHTML`, but the elements inside the wrapper will still be recreated.

```js
jQuery(function() {
    var wrapper = $('h2:first').parent().parent()[0];
    wrapper.outerHTML = wrapper.outerHTML.replace('<h2', '</div><div class="foo"><h2');
});
```

```css
.foo {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>dummy paragraph</p>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>dummy paragraph</p>
    <p>dummy paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works if the original `.foo` doesn't contain any text node children.  Otherwise, they won't get moved.

Comment: Thanks for this option, is it somehow possible to add a closing tag in anyway directly?

Comment: @coder no it's not possible. You need to understand that the html is converted to dom node objects by the browser.

Comment: @coder It's only sort-of possible, by use of innerHTML/outerHTML, and using string replace, but it brings with it some potentially negative side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from documentation insert before:

http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

That it is actually adding an element created with jquery like this

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).insertBefore( ".inner" );
```

resulting on this;

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <p>Test</p>
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <p>Test</p>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

**So it is a valid div html created with jquery**

Answer (score 0):

As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14737115/2397327), you cannot add an independent closing tag to the DOM.

The easiest way I think this would be possible is to to add two `<div>` elements to the DOM, and then remove the extra tags (the first `<div>` and the last `</div>`) as necessary.

Comment: You can't manipulate the dom by removing a closing tag ...there is no way to do that. Answer doesn't make much more sense than the question does

Comment: @charlietfl Because (AFAIK) there is no way to do it, this is just a suggestion. And although you cannot manipulate the DOM to remove a closing tag, you can use regex to remove it (although this is bad practice --- but again, this is just a suggestion if all else fails).